# POS simulator for development purposes

Tags: .net, windows, emulation, simulator, point-of-sale

Are there any POS simulators for windows OS for development purposes? I have to develop a .NET application which uses POS printer and drawer, but I don't have one right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft POS for .NET has a printer simulator. It may have a cash drawer simulator too, I'm not sure. The printer simulator is very primitive.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing the extract model there isnt much I can do.
but if you know the model ask the tech support for an API.

from my experience POS printer is just a regular printer. the standard printing API will work.

POS drawers usually use very simple COM interface probably with a single command.

so for the printer. Just use standard .net printing API. for manual tests print to PDF with small width "paper"

for the drawer? just have a drawer class with single method OPEN that always returns success.
when you get to work with the real printer make the function handle its API.